# RegExp must have \w+ and \s+ characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been trying to create a RegExp that makes sure a sure has entered at least one word and at least one space.  I tried to use this:

`/\w+\s+/`

But that makes sure that there is a word AFTER a space.  I just want to make sure there is both in a string.  They don't need to be in the order of the above RegExp.

How can I make the RegExp work, but without matching the order?

Comment: could you post some possible and impossible matches?

Comment: It SHOULD match "Hello, dude."  It should NOT match "Hello,dude".

Comment: There are a lot of answers to my question.  However, I do not want to simply pick the one that is upvoted.  Please give a detailed explanation of why your regex works, and maybe why mine doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two things:

- Is there a word character?
- Is there a space?

Two things.

- `str.match(/\w/)`
- `str.match(/\s/)`

So why are you trying to do them as one step?

```
if( str.match(/\w/) && str.match(/\s/))
```

---

> There are a lot of answers to my question. However, I do not want to simply pick the one that is upvoted. Please give a detailed explanation of why your regex works, and maybe why mine doesn't.

My answer provides the simplest solution. It is very clear to anyone reading it that we are checking "if it has a word character, and if it contains a space character". It is also very easy to expand on, such as if you want to add another check.

zyklus' answer (`/(?=.*?\w)(?=.*?\s)/`) is the fastest when speed-tested on a 50Kb string of input. In more common cases (ie. 100 character at most), this speed difference will be practically non-existent. It is twice as fast as my answer, but "2 * very small number = very small number". It's easy enough to add new test cases (just add another `(?=.*something)` block) but is less humanly-obvious as to what it does.

Jacob's answer (`(\w+.*\s+)|(\s+.*\w+)`) does quite literally what you asked, checking first if there is a word character and then a space character, then checks the other way around before failing. It works, however it is slower. Furthermore, if you decide to add a new test case, you'd get something like `(\w+.*\s+.*\d+)|(\w+.*\d+.*\s)|(\s+.*\w+.*\d+)|(\s+.*\d+.*\w+)|(\d+.*\w+.*\s+)|‌​(\d+.*\s+.*\w+)`. It only gets worse if you add a fourth test (24 arrangements to check) and is unreadably ugly. Do not use this answer.

Other answers are variants of existing ones.

Comment: @Godisgood Well sure. But I want to teach you that the best solution to a problem is usually the easiest one.

Comment: And I'll be honest: killing you? Is hard. --GLaDOS

Comment: There are a lot of answers to my question. However, I do not want to simply pick the one that is upvoted. Please give a detailed explanation of why your regex works, and maybe why mine doesn't.

Comment: @Godisgood I have edited my answer with commentary on the answers here.

Comment: Thank you.  I am going with your answer, because I do understand it the way you explain it.  Thank you others, for your help as well.  +1 for your help.

Comment: "My answer provides the simplest solution" and the worst at the same time.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Explain.

Answer (score 6):

```
/(?=.*?\w)(?=.*?\s)/
```

`?=` means "look-ahead", and `.*` means "any number of characters"

So "find any number of characters then a `\w`", "find any number of characters and a `\s`"

Another thing to note about how this works, look-aheads are "non-matching", making it so that this can match in any order.

Comment: So if I use `?`, then it will match in any order?

Comment: The efficiency nut in me is thinking that this should be optimised. `/(?=\W*\w)(?=\S*\s)/`, for instance. Or `/(?=.*?\w)(?=.*?\s)/`. Either way, it should match as little as needed to assert the match.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol -- Haha, fair enough.  I'll edit to `.*?` -- Though I'm not certain if the regex engine would optimize this or not since it's part of a look-ahead?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol -- http://jsperf.com/greedy-vs-non-greedy-lookahead Definitely not optimized (at least in Chrome)

Comment: @zyklus I figured non-greedy would be faster. Didn't realise it'd be that big of a difference! Wow!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol -- Well I tested it against a ~50KB string

Comment: There are a lot of answers to my question. However, I do not want to simply pick the one that is upvoted. Please give a detailed explanation of why your regex works, and maybe why mine doesn't.

Comment: @Godisgood -- I did explain it.  Read up on "regular expression look-aheads" if you need more of an explanation, as until you understand the concept it may not make much sense, but I'm not going to write a book here to explain it :)

Comment: I understand, @zyklus.  But, why should I use yours instead of @NiettheDarkAbsol's?

Comment: @Godisgood -- No reason, use whichever one you prefer :)  Mine is harder to understand and might lead to confusion later, but it's also a single regex that, in some situations, might be helpful.  For instance if you have a code fork that runs one of N regexes, look-ahead patterns eliminate the need for different logical branches.  In a one-off, I would say use this if you understand it, since looking at it 3 months from now might confuse you if you don't :)

Comment: Yes, zyklus.  I've been reading about look-aheads and combined with @niet's answer, I do understand yours.  +1.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to do it in one RegEx for some reason:

```
(\w+.*\s+)|(\s+.*\w+)
```

Can be handy if you're working with a library that only enables you to use a single regular expression.

Comment: This answer is technically correct, but let's say I want to ensure that there is at least one digit in there as well - your answer would explode to `(\w+.*\s+.*\d+)|(\w+.*\d+.*\s)|(\s+.*\w+.*\d+)|(\s+.*\d+.*\w+)|(\d+.*\w+.*\s+)|(\d+.*\s+.*\w+)` and it only gets worse from there.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Yes but this is not the case here, there are only two characters to find. And this kind of approach can be improved like this: `(?=[\w\s])(?:\w+\S*\s|\s+\W*\w)` that avoids to parse the string twice and to test the alternation on each character. However, if pre-analysis is smart enough the lookahead technic may be more performant.